# Free Google Analytics plugin that works with Wordpress in network mode (WPMU)?

Tags: multisite, google-analytics

Is there any free Google Analytics plugin that works with WPMU?

Please suggest only if you use it and it works.

Comment: Do you need features or to just add the analytics tracking code?

Comment: The feture would be to work, for example the most famous GA plugin doesn't work well with WPMU, it just not add the code to the page.

Comment: Can you not just add the tracking code to your templates?

Comment: What do you need? Different tracking codes for different sites?

Answer (score 1):

**[Google Analyticator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analyticator/)** plugin adds the necessary JavaScript code to enable Google Analytics tracking across your site(s). It also includes widgets for Analytics data display.

Answer (score 1):

**[Google Analytics for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/)** by Joost de Valk, is a well maintained plugin that enables Google Analytics tracking across your WordPress site(s) easily and with lots of metadata including — views per author & category, automatic tracking of outbound clicks and pageviews.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/header-footer/ plugin for that. That pretty much help me put google analytics code, google verification codes and other vendors codes on my site without installing lots of plugin to do the same thing. You might want to try this. **But this is not a analytics plugin.**